# Can I override PlaceController in gwt app

Tags: gwt

I would like to implement new method to place controller, like 'goToPreviousPlace()'. In my app gwt place controller is used. I use gin to injection.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply call

```
History.back();
```

Comment: It'is good solution, but not enought for me. If user would toggle between two tabs, and close them, there is posibillity for him to visit closed tabs, and if he would close last tab, he would be redirect to login page, and this is bad behaviour. I need more controll, this is why I would like to use  my methods from my controller.

Comment: You don't want tabs to be "places" - they are states of a particular view which can be added to the History as tokens (e.g. #MainView:tab1). Your presenter/activity should be able to display a "default" state of that view if a tab corresponding to the token is no longer available. Generally, it's not a good idea to push the logic that belongs to activities to the PlaceController.